Connecting flush mounted ceiling light
Just bought flush MOON ceiling light. The ceiling receptacle has red(live),yellow (live) and white pair (zero) wires.
How to connect black and white wires to this?
Thanks
VS

We need a few pictures of the fixture and how the old one was wired.  what part of the planet are you on?

What country are you located in? Black and white wires imply North America but the wire colors for your fixture don’t. Also, your terminology doesn’t make sense. You should have a hot, a neutral and a ground, not two “lives” and a “zero”.

Red & yellow wires are perfectly legal for hot wires in the US if they are individual wires run in conduit. Pics are needed so we can see what you're seeing.

And if in conduit, the whites are supposed to be neutrals.  Two hots do make life interesting.  One should be a continuation to something else(and dead if not connected) or a switch hot.

one of the wires looks like a painted black wire

In the US, my question would be: are the two hots on the same phase (possibly separate control for a light and ceiling fan, possibly switch loop, 120V) or opposite phases (240V between them)?
